# Android studio - Gradle - GitHub Repo

Tags: android, maven, github, gradle, android-studio

Does anyone have an idea if it's possible to use a github repo as a dependency, without it being published to maven central.

Let's say I'm developing an android library that has it's own github repo. I'd like to be able to "compile" this library has gradle dependency, in my android studio project, without having to publish to maven central (at least for the moment).

In other words : I want to use a dependency that is not on maven central. It's a straight github repo (an android library that also uses gradle).

I'd like my build.gradle to do something like this :

```
dependencies {
  // Google Play Services (normal dependency)
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.2.08"

  // The library I want to pull from github
  compile "path_to_my_github_repo"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/gVDWMCAdxd8 ?

Comment: Maybe this: https://github.com/bat-cha/gradle-plugin-git-dependencies

Comment: @CommonsWare not really. The Git dependencies plugin seems to be what i'm looking for. 

Unfortunately, I already had a look at it, but the issues says it's not compatible with android-plugin.

Comment: Updated my question to include more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) with Maven, Gradle and sbt.

However, I would strongly suggest to use binary artifact instead so that you are guaranteed that it is the same upon each build of your application, you control the artifact storage and you are using the official release of a project and not some downstream build. It will also make your builds much faster and more stable.

Publishing to the Central Repository is free, easy and well documented at e.g. http://central.sonatype.org/pages/producers.html and specifically for Gradle at http://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html. You can also find [lots of real world examples on the Nexus community site.](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/?s=gradle&submit=Search)

If you do not control the project you want to consume, I would suggest to send these pointers to the project and maybe even help them with a pull request ;-)

Comment: +1 for JitPack. Btw, it only builds the first time and then you get the same artifact every time. That makes repeated builds fast

Comment: Problem of course still is that you do NOT use the officially released artifact of that project and you are also do not get workind IDE integration or automatic inclusion of javadoc and sources.

Comment: That does depend on the project indeed. If their build produces sources/javadoc then you get IDE inclusion. Can be official release as well, eg: http://quickml.org

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible and there is an unofficial gradle plugin called [Gradle Git Repo plugin](https://github.com/layerhq/gradle-git-repo-plugin) that claims to do what you're looking for. Note however, that I did not play with it myself to verify that it works.

Comment: there's also jitpack

Answer (score -1):

What you need to use is a binary repository. It will contain your dependencies during development.
If you plan to publish your package to [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) (and maven central) eventually, you can get a free Artifactory account in [oss.jfrog.org](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26083425).
Once doing that, your CI server can deploy your dependency to it and Gradle will resolve it from there.